# AngularJs - TypeError: Cannot set property 'showGreeting' of null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Im using yeoman angularjs-fullstack to generate my project. 
And now Im trying to modify it to my liking.
Im quite new with angularJS and very green with TypeScript so please give me loads of feedback and not just the answer to why its not working. :)

Main.html:

```
    <div ng-if=main.isLoggedIn()>
    <div ng-if="main.timeOutGreeting()">
        <div ng-show="main.showGreeting">
            <header class="hero-unit" id="banner">
                <div class="container">
                    <h1>Hi!</h1>
                    <p class="lead">Welcome back, mr b>{{main.currentUser().name}}</b></p>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and mainController.ts:

```
'use strict';

(function() {

class MainController {

  showGreeting = true;

  constructor(Auth, $state, $timeout) {
    this.user = {};
    this.isLoggedIn = Auth.isLoggedIn;
    this.isAdmin = Auth.isAdmin;
    this.currentUser = Auth.getCurrentUser;

    this.$state = $state;
    this.$timeout = $timeout;

  }

  goToLogin() {
    this.$state.go('login');
  }

  timeOutGreeting() {
    this.$timeout(function() {
        this.showGreeting = false;
    }, 3000);
  }
}

angular.module('noteApp')
  .controller('MainController', MainController);

})();
```

The aim is that the "Hi! Welcome back, mr User" should be visible only for a short while (3s) before disappearing. So please help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to add the $scope "service" to your controllers constructor.
2. You need to add a static $inject = ['service1', 'service2'] with all your services (in the exact same order as they are in the constructor). This is a way for angular to know which services you want, as it can't read the service names from the constructor. This also ensures that your script works when minified.
3. You neeed to use the lambda/fat arrow syntax for your function inside the $timeout. E.g. this.$timeout(() => { this.$scope.main.showGreeting = true; });

The lamda syntax will create a reference to the class' this object, instead of the local functions this object.

I hope these hints will help you :)

I'm on a phone, so sorry for the lack of actual implementation sample.

Answer (score 1):

an `ng-if="..."` will not throw a browser error if there is invalid JS in the `ng-if`.  Just from looking at your code (briefly), I don't think "main" is ever defined on $scope.  Perhaps in your controller, you should add `$scope.main = this;`.  After that, within your controller's scope, main will be a reference to the controller instance.

Answer (score 1):

use arrow functions :)

`timeOutGreeting() {
    this.$timeout(() => {
        this.showGreeting = false;
    }, 3000);
  }`